# best ways to store long string as PDA seed

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

as we all know - the PDA seed string is limited by 30 characters. Is there any way to keep long strings like "my name is gajesh" (this is just an example but I want to add it for a different purpose) as PDA seeds? maybe with hashing or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you used in the other question is correct, just that you implemented it in the wrong way. You used the SHA-256 hash of the string as a seed and it should do the job. Your code:

```
anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(name.as_bytes()).to_string().as_bytes()
```

You called `to_string()` method on the `Hash` which returns the `String` in `Base58` encoding. This is where you made the mistake. The length of Base58 encoding of the SHA-256 string is `44`. But the maximum length of the seed can be `32`.

To solve the issue, don't convert the `Hash` into string. So your seed should be like this:

```
&anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(name.as_bytes()).to_bytes()
```

Then on the client-side (if you are using Node.js):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let hexString = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(name,'utf-8').digest('hex');
let seed = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(hexString,'hex'));

let [myPDA, _] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress([
    seed
],programId);
```

The seed is Uint8Array of the buffer of SHA-256 string which is a 256-bit number. So the length of the seed array will be `32` which is the maximum permissible seed length limit.

Comment: `expected an array with a fixed size of 4 elements, found one with 32 elements`

Comment: Can you show the part of the code where you are initialising PDA with the above seed? It is hard to understand what went wrong without seeing how you used the seed.

Comment: i used this - `&anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(name.as_bytes()).to_bytes()`

Comment: I have added a code here: https://github.com/0xShuk/String-as-PDA. Tell me if it works for you.